# Pivot Table with python win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I try to make excel file with Python. For that I use win32com because that seem the best way to make pivot table (pandas is not a good solution), but I have some troubles.

First when I try to make a pivot table on Sheet where there is already a pivot table i have that error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-62ca0c0e21ec>", line 1, in <module>
    PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName=PivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

  File "C:\Users\LPLOUV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\PivotCache.py", line 45, in CreatePivotTable
    , TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Une exception s’est produite.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Second I need to remake some pivot table that exist already, so I need to delete some pivote table from sheet but I don't know how I can make that.

Until there I use this code:

```
import os
import win32com.client
import time



time_first = time.time()

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\msmith\Desktop')




Excel   = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') # Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

win32c = win32com.client.constants

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open('excel_file.xlsx')

Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

xldata = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value
data_pivot = xldata[:24291]


cl1 = Sheet1.Cells(1,1)
cl2 = Sheet1.Cells(1+len(data_pivot)-1,1+len(data_pivot[0])-1)
PivotSourceRange = Sheet1.Range(cl1,cl2)

cl3=Sheet2.Cells(200,200)
PivotTargetRange=  Sheet2.Range(cl3,cl3)
PivotTableName = 'ReportPivotTable'


PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName=PivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)


PivotTable.PivotFields('A').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
PivotTable.PivotFields('A').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('B').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('B').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('B').CurrentPage = 'b'
PivotTable.PivotFields('C').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('C').Position = 2
PivotTable.PivotFields('C').CurrentPage = 5

PivotTable.PivotFields('D').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('D').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('D').CurrentPage = 'd'




PivotTable.PivotFields('E').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('E').Position = 3
PivotTable.PivotFields('E').CurrentPage = "(All)"
PivotTable.PivotFields('D').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
PivotTable.PivotFields('D').Position = 1



DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('F'), Function = win32c.xlSum)
DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('G'), Function = win32c.xlSum)

wb.SaveAs('excel_file.xlsx')
Excel.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a blank field in your data. For example:

This will give you the error.

[image]

This will not.

[image]